# How can I copy data from one google sheet to another? (in Appscript)

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to move data from one G-sheet to another not using importrange.
How can I do this in Appscript?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID)
var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME)
var values = sheet.getRange(RANGE_NOTATION).getValues()
```

and in your main sheet

```
var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME)
sheet.getRange(RANGE_NOTATION).setValues(values)
```

then delete the original

Answer (score 0):

From the main sheet from where you want to extract data,use something like this :-

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_of_sheet) var ssname = ss.getSheetByName(Name_Of_that_particular_Sheet_in_theSpreadSheet) var DataCopied = ssname.getRange('A1:B').getValues() // "A1:B is an example StringNotation of that range from where you want to copy the data"`

Now you have extracted the data from that sheet, use this to paste it on another sheet

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_of_Secondsheet) var ssname = ss.getSheetByName(Name_Of_that_particular_Sheet_in_theSpreadSheet) // where you want paste the data ssname.getRange('A1:B').setValues(DataCopied) // setValues will paste the data you copied.`

Make sure to use the same rangeNotation which you've used while copying the data from main sheet.
For more information, you can refer to documentation :- [ServiceDoc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)